# @font-face + jQuery height() in Chrome (window.load solution not working)

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, font-face

I need to get the height of an element, which contains text with @fontface applied. I've tried $(window).load solution, but that is working in IE, Firefox, but not in Chrome (19dev). I have also tried to setTimeout (1s, 2s etc.) for my plugin init function... nothing...

I know about Google WebfontLoader, but I would rather to include webfonts as css files.

Any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height of the element using http://api.jquery.com/height/.

```
var elementHeight = $(this).height();
```

What's not working in Chrome: the @fontface styles or getting the element height? Try switching to the stable version of Chrome and see if that helps. The dev build can be a little quirky.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to get height of the element with jQuery. The problem is that the browser loads fontface too late, so height() is not working properly. As I said, using $(window).load instead $(document).ready solves this problem in most browsers, but not in current Chrome.

Comment: It may be an issue with that Chrome dev build if you're not seeing this in any other browsers. Did you try the stable version of Chrome?